# Scenebuilder ID's

Tags: java, javafx

The components I'm creating in Scenebuilder need to be given an identity from the controller class. Right now I am typing out declarations for buttons, textareas and such. Is there any way to have an object automatically created in the code when I create it in the fxml file?

Comment: In Netbeans, one would select the fxml file and select the Source -> Make Controller to automatically generate or update the controller class.

Comment: Okay thanks. This worked. You need to first enter a name for the id in SceneBuilder in the 'fx:id' box, then Source -> Make Controller in NetBeans.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SceneBuilder there is a menu option `View | Show Sample Controller Skeleton`.  You can manually copy and paste from the skeleton into your controller file to get matching code references to the FXML ids.

Using SceneBuilder alone, the task to generate IDs in your controller code is not as completely automated as you requested.  However, as WillShackleford pointed out in comments, some IDEs can provide some extension services to help automate tasks further (though I don't have specific information on that).

Answer (score 0):

The order must go

1. Controller
2. SceneBuilder

to use integrated features. Note that the .fxml and controller *must* be in the same directory, and scenebuilder doesn't always refresh automatically. In addition to the skeleton dropdown, there are dropdowns next to the id's from which you can select the object from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

since I'm using NetBeans, Will answered my question in the comment. If you fill the 'fx:id' field (in SceneBuilder) with any id name and the select both the controller file and the fxml (in NetBeans) and then select Source --> Make Controller and id will be creates in the source code. Thanks for the help!